# Restore Ubuntu from Dell Laptop

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 14R that came with Ubuntu 11.1 installed from the Factory. I had multiple troubles and I had to re-install, for which I used an 12.04 ISO that I downloaded from Ubuntu site.

Now, the System boots but some stuff -like Touchpad or GPU acceleration- is not working so I want to restore the Factory version. Is that possible? Some forums direct to a Recovery partition, but I don't have one (I only see a Dell Utility one)

Comment: try press F8 during the boot - you should see something like restore menu

Answer (score 2):

1. Shut down your machine
2. Press "Shift" button and simultaneously press "Power"...keep "Shift" button pressed.
3. System will open with a few options ....one of the options will be - Restore Factory settings...

Comment: If this doesn't work, hit Ctrl+Alt+Del during boot. It will reboot to the menu